# MacBook Air syncing with my iTunes on my iPhone

Tags: iphone, data-synchronization, macbook-pro

I plugged my iPhone into my MacBook thinking that all my iTunes music on my iPhone would magically sync onto my new MacBook Air... unfortunately not, there is only one song in my iTunes library on my MacBook & my iPhone has some purchased songs unable to be played now. I'm unable to click on `devices` because it's greyed out. How do I get the music on my iPhone onto my new computer & my purchased material back?

Comment: This is a "MACbook": http://maccosmetics.yourfreebies.net/wp-content/uploads/2012/09/mac-bible.jpg

Comment: MAC is a makeup company...

Answer (score 1):

You can not just drag and drop music from an iPhone when connected to the computer, though there are software for that. I would suggest, Download a software such as iPod access, which can help you extract the songs directly from the iPhone.